# How to update HTML content with javascript but get contents using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a php script called `get_info.php` In this file is a simple function called `get_data()` which takes the user submitted input and returns an array.

I have a HTML page called `index.html`. When the user hits submit, I would like the page not NOT refresh, but rather, it called the `get_data()` PHP function and updates the HTML.

---

**My questions:**

1. I do not want other websites/people using my `get_data()` function to grab data. Whats the best way I can prevent other websites from using my `get_data()` function? For example, just echo-ing the array on `get_info.php` means other websites can just use `file_get_contents` on my script. I want people to use my `index.html` to get the data, not using my php script directly.
2. Could someone show me how to update the HTML content by grabbing the info it gets from the `get_data()` function? As well as how I could show the user there was an error if their input is incorrect (for example, if the user entered a number, thats invalid, and should tell the user to enter letters only).

---

**get_info.php**

```
<?php

function get_data($input) {
    $arr['image'] = "https://example.com/$input";
    $arr['username'] = "$input" . rand(1, 50);
    return $arr;
}

function checkInput($input) {
    if (ctype_alpha($input))
        return true;

    return false;
}

if (isset($_POST['userInput'])) {

    $isValid = checkInput($_POST['userInput']);

    if ($isValid)
        $info = get_data($_POST['userInput']);
        // Now some how give this array to index.html
    else {
        // I throw an error, but how would I show
        // the user that the input they entered is
        // invalid?
    }
}
```

---

**index.html**

```js
// Not sure what to do here, but I want to set the myImage
// and myUsername to what I get from the get_data() array.
function updateMyPage() {
    document.getElementById("myImage").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("myUsername").innerHTML = "";
    showMainCont()
}

// Shows the main container
function showMainCont() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mainCont");
    x.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.myMain {
    display:none;
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
User Input:
<input type="text" name="userInput"><br>
<button onclick="updateMyPage()">Submit</button>

<div class="myMain" id="mainCont">
    <div id="myImage"></div>
    <div id="myUsername"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) for fetching data without refreshing the page.

**Question 1 -**

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is there to prevent other users/websites from using your script and all modern browsers have that support by default.

**Question 2 -**

You can just use a normal PHP script which echo you content and dump that content into the *div* you want using javascript.